# bash / awk : look for the number in the string matching the pattern

Tags: bash, awk

within some log.dat there is a line provided in the following format

```
DELTA TOTAL                -17.0262               10.3718              1.0813
```

I need to find the string (always starts with DELTA TOTAL) and find a negative number in its second column (-17.0262) and save it as a bash variable using the algorithm:

```
NUMBER="$(awk '' file.dat)"
```

so echo $number should give me -17.03  ( better to keep only 2 numbers after .)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```bash
$ awk '{v=$1" "$2; if (v~/^DELTA TOTAL/){printf ("%.2f\n", $3)}}' file
-17.03
```

Comment: `v=$1" "$2; if (v~/^DELTA TOTAL/)` = `/^DELTA TOTAL/`